# Need help improving my c++ and class creation 2

Tags: c++

i wanna know where i can improve my program as well as i have run into a problem with my code.

this is my hero class and source, it is telling me i have `hero h;` calling a deleted function as well as how do i pass stats through this function? until i have this figured out i had `//` out the classes constructor.

```
 class hero : public Stats {
    //protected:

public:



    void raceAndClass() {

        Stats S(10,10,10,10,10,10);
        race c_race(race::orc, S);
        //classes c_classes(classes::fighter, modStats, sneak, bluff, deplomacy, swim, mana, run);
        using namespace std;
        }
};


int main()
{
        hero H;
        H.raceAndClass();
        while (true);

}
```

here is my next class stats

```
   class Stats {
    public:
        int //default stats
            Str = 10,
            Dex = 10,
            Con = 10,
            Int = 10,
            Wis = 10,
            Chr = 10;

    Stats(int STR, int DEX, int CON, int INT, int WIS, int CHR) :
        Str(STR), Dex(DEX), Con(CON), Int(INT), Wis(WIS), Chr(CHR) {
    }
};
```

my race cpp and header

```
  #include"stats.h"

class race {
public:
    enum raceOpt { orc, elf, human };

    race(raceOpt c_raceOpt, Stats &stats);


    //race opt outcomes 
    void ORC(Stats& stats) {
        stats.Str += 2;
        stats.Int -= 2;
        stats.Chr -= 2;
    }
    void ELF(Stats &stats) {
        //elf code and stat changes
    }

    void HUMAN(Stats &stats) {


}
    };


#include"race.h"

race::race(raceOpt c_raceOpt, Stats &stats) {
    switch (c_raceOpt) {
    case orc:
        ORC(stats);
        break;
    case human:
        //human code
        break;
    case elf:
        //elf code
        break;
    }
}
```

and finally my classes cpp & header.(not currently being called)

```
#include"stats.h"

class classes {
public:
    enum classOpt { fighter, mage, soccerPlayer };

    classes(classOpt c_classOpt, double ModStats[_MAX_PATH], int& Sneak, int& Bluff, int& Deplomacy, int& Swim, int& Mana, int& Run);

    void Fighter(int& SWIM, int& RUN, int& BLUFF, double ModStats[_MAX_PATH]) {
        SWIM = static_cast<int>(SWIM + std::round(((ModStats[1] * 2.3))));
        RUN = static_cast<int>(RUN + (std::round(((ModStats[1] * 2)))));
        BLUFF = static_cast<int>(BLUFF + std::round(((ModStats[0] * 2.5))));

    }
    void Mage(int& MANA, int& DEPLOMACY, int& BLUFF, double ModStats[_MAX_PATH]) {
        //code to be added

    }
    void SoccerPlayer(int& RUN, int& SWIM, int& DEPLOMACY, int& SNEAK, double ModStats[_MAX_PATH]) {
        //code to be added

    }
};

#include"classes.h"


classes::classes(classOpt c_classOpt, double ModStats[_MAX_PATH], int& Sneak, int& Bluff, int& Deplomacy, int& Swim, int& Mana, int& Run) {
    switch (c_classOpt) {
    case fighter:
        Fighter(Swim, Run, Bluff, ModStats);
        break;
    case mage:
        Mage(Mana, Deplomacy, Bluff, ModStats);
        break;
    case soccerPlayer:
        SoccerPlayer(Run, Swim, Deplomacy, Sneak, ModStats);
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you try and rephrase you question? Its hard to interpret.

Comment: Are you getting an error message? Can you tell us what it is? Your statement "it is telling me i have hero h; calling a deleted function" sounds like you might be getting an error message.

Comment: i am trying to pass stats integers through this constructor so they can be called and modified later.

Comment: If your code works, consider posting to [codereview.se].

Comment: Error C2280 'hero::hero(void)': attempting to reference a deleted

Comment: In your `hero` class, which is derived from `Stats`, why is there a local `Stats` variable in the method?

Comment: Your `RaceAndClass` method is worthless.  It has local variables that are intialized, but disappear after execution leaves the method.  The `using namespace std;` is also worthless where it is.  BTW, don't put `using namespace std;` in header files.

Comment: hero is calling stats constructor to so it can be passed into the race constructor so the stats can be modified. analogy ever play D&D every character has there stats which then effect other skills but those stats are changed slightly based on race. like i roll 15 for orc then +2 for being an orc, now my str is 17 and that helps my skill at climbing. i guess ;p

Comment: the namespcae std: was used b4 for cout & endl but i removed those but left the std. should i then change the raceAndClass to be a constructor for hero?

Answer (score 1):

Your `hero` class derives from `Stats`. Your `Stats` class requires a constructor call with a bunch of arguments; there is no default constructor. Therefore, you cannot call the default `hero` constructor with just `hero H;`, because there isn't one (that's where the compiler tells you that you can't reference a deleted method). You will need to implement a no-argument constructor for `hero`, which calls the `Stats` constructor with suitable arguments.

Comment: okey i know this  is probably gonna sound bad but do you have a reference i learn from examples?

Comment: @PiePie: A quick Google search found this which looks like it addresses the problems you're having: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/85-constructors/

Answer (score 0):

i redid my stats class and my hero class!!! i will also take my stats class and add more stats/skills to it as well as get my classes class refinded. thanks for the help!!!

```
#pragma once
class Stats {
public:
    int //default stats
        Str = 10,
        Dex = 10,
        Con = 10,
        Int = 10,
        Wis = 10,
        Chr = 10;

    Stats(){}
};


//hero class vvvvv

class hero : public Stats {
private:
    Stats s;
public:

     hero() {

         race c_race(race::orc, s);
         std::cout << s.Str << std::endl;
         std::cout << s.Int << std::endl;
         std::cout << s.Chr << std::endl;
         std::cout << s.Wis << std::endl;
        //classes c_classes(classes::fighter, modStats, sneak, bluff, deplomacy, swim, mana, run);

        }
};
```

Comment: one more quick question, its simple so i dont feel i should make another question page. would it be ok to use my class Stats for seval other creatures such as an any bandit? or should i make a whole other class for those creatures. i wanna minimize my code.